# Convert ts-node package.json script to nodejs package.json script when building

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a TypeScript project with this structure:

- root

  - src

    - index.ts
  - package.json
  - dist

    - index.js
    - package.json

This will be hosted in Azure Web Apps. Currently I have my start script more or less like this:

```
"start": "ts-node index.ts"
```

I would like build to `dist/` folder and have the script be:

```
"start": "node index.js"
```

As I will only be deploying contents of `dist/`. Grunt is used to build/copy (I've found this package called [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) but I don't know if that's a good approach).

Is there any way to achieve this, or do I need to restructure `dist/`? The only other production TypeScript/Node.js project I've worked on is an Azure Function which leverages azure-functions-core-tools' `func host start` from `dist/`.

Comment: `node dist/index.js`?

Comment: Won't that only work from root directory? 
Is the solution just to have different scripts depending on where I'm running it?
So a dev script for local, and then start can be when deployed.

Comment: Yes, typically something like `ts-node index.ts` would be the `dev` script. But are you copying the root `package.json` into `dist/`? Or is that a separate file?

Comment: copying the root package.json into dist/

Comment: Note you can use e.g. `files`, `main`, `types` in `package.json` to be able to keep the package file in the root and still only distribute the compiled output (see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/ts-tdd/commit/04f923f5f6d37b19ef4bfcaae1395304cd78695e) - that gives you more dev/prod parity and lets you control everything from the root directory. Then you have `"dev": "ts-node src/index.ts"` and `"start": "node dist/index.js"`.

Comment: I think your last comment @jonrsharpe is exactly what I'm looking for